# Один из принципов SOLID - SRP

Tags: c++, ооп, solid

у меня есть общий класс File, который наследуется от класса FileWrite, который выполняют запись данных в файл, и от класса FileSearch, который выполняет поиск информации по файлу. Скажите есть ли тут нарушение принципа SRP(single-responsibility principle)?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: solidworks - это такая программа (для которой часто пишут плагины), не имеющая отношения к SOLID.

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать

Comment: Здесь классы ни за что не отвечают, в просто напиханы несвязанные статические функции, которым явно было бы лучше в пространстве имен.

Comment: я вот сильно сомневаюсь, что класс файл должен уметь искать в себе. Скорее всего должен быть класс искателя, который получает себе указатель/ссылку на интерфейс ридера (который файл должен реализовать) и уже читает и ищет.

Comment: @KoVadim ну если отвлечься от названия "файл" - то в принципе логично. В том же spring java  ты создаешь свой "репозиторий" наследуясь от "репозиторий который может постранично" , тот в свою очередь наслдуется от "репозиторий в котором можно искать"  ( грубо говоря ) и т д

Comment: в java это нормально - наплодить 100500 классов и говорить, что это нормально в ООП (хотя java не является ООП языком:) и пример с spring показывает ещё раз это). Но не будет зацикливаться на bad practice, а также тыкать:)

Comment: @KoVadim вы видимо не читали книгу основоположника SOLID, Мартина, - clean architecture. Он там в половине случаев рассказывая про ооп и обьясняя solid ссылается на  java примеры, в том числе тот самый спринг.

Comment: ох ох. читал, читал я дядька Боба. На java можно писать с использованием парадигмы ООП, но это не значит, что любой код на джава есть кодом ООП.

Comment: То же самое можно сказать про любой язык. Вообще боб и про ооп пишет что не сильно оно добавляет в солид :) и без него можно писать хорошо

Answer (score 4):

1. Single responsibility principle - не означает что компонент должен отвечать за одно действие, но означает что должна быть одна (всмысле одна и та же) причина изменения для кода в этом классе. То есть если запись в файл и поиск по файлу меняется по одной и той же причине (потому что сменился формат файла например) - то эти функции должны быть помещены в один компонет, в один и тот же класс. Если меняются по разным причинам - например чтение более низкоуровневое и зависит от файловой системы или носителя, а поиск - не зависит, он зависит только от чтения - тогда можно разбить в разные компоненты.
2. У вас сделанно наследование немного не логично получается что может быть класс умеющий искать по файлу, но не
   читать. Но поиск подразумевает чтение файла.

Comment: Cпасибо за ответ. Хотел бы уточнить, если я Вас правильно понял, то должно получиться примерно вот так?

class FileAction {
public:
 bool findOne(const string& fileName, TypeMethod Object::* method, any_type value, Object& object);
 void findAll(const string& nameFile, vector<T>& savedObject);
 void reWrite(const string& fileName, vector<T>& array);
 void addData(const string& fileName, T& object);
 void getUnicSeed(const string& nameFile, T& obj);
 bool is_file_exist(const string& fileName);
};

Comment: Примерно да. Если ваш этот класс сильно разрастется и его будет сложно поддерживать, тогда его можно будет разбить, только функции чтения-записи будут в родительском а разный поиск, зависящий от них, в дочернем